# How do I resolve slow behavior with webpack's less-loader and bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, webpack

I have been dealing with slow builds using the `less-loader` for some time now (4-8 seconds using the watcher).

Here is my general config:
https://gist.github.com/paltman/6f49d7ebf0142b27f459

I have narrowed down the issue to the import of `bootstrap.less`.

When I compile `bootstrap.less` using `lessc` from command line it takes about 1s. Any reason why it would be 8x slower using `less-loader`?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Crossposted an [issue on less-loader repo](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader/issues/54)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's still actual. I've had the same performance issue compiling less files into css. Discovered that using `css-loader` 0.15.0+ versions decrease css imports performance. 0.14.5 `css-loader` version works good to me. See https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/124 discussion for further info.